# ANTLR3 C# library as a portable .NET library

Tags: windows-8, antlr

I am trying to write an app for Win 8 that uses ANTLR3. Is their a version of the ANTLR .NET runtime that runs on Win 8 (a portable .NET Library)?

Answer (score 1):

No. However, a portable release of the C# target for ANTLR 4 is nearly complete.

You can request the feature for ANTLR 3 on the project's issue tracker here:
https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs/issues

Comment: I think the existing 3.0 runtime can be made to Portable as well. If 4.0 can be made available soon then I will switch.

Comment: By "Portable", do you mean .net PCL?  Is that out yet?